# Should I recalculate Bone Rolls?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, keyframes

So I have a few animations I wanna export to Unreal Engine. I looked at my Armature and realized that I have not recalculate the rolls of the Bones in edit mode. I made not a lot of animations but it took so long for me to get them right. I mean I got the animations I wanted, but if the rolls are not aligned correctly, even if the animation is still fine, should I be worried? Should I recalculate the Rolls?

BTW: The main reason I ask this is because I made an animation where the character is sitting down but he just slightly jitters a bit for some reason. I understand it has to do with the IK but I thought it'd have to do with the recalculate rolls. I did this once but as you'd expect the Armature was all out of whack so I gotta redo the whole pose / animation. However, I noticed the jittering was still there. So now here I am looking for help on this, wondering do I start over with my work or keep going?